# opacity and style undefined when accesing element in js but defined in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

With this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mungbeans/f2ne6/2/

why is the opacity undefined when accessed in js when its defined in the css?

I presume the answer is because the style is also undefined, why is that, does the style need adding somewhere explicitly before the opacity can be defined?

EDIT
the lack of [] is a typo created as I copied from source to fiddle. The style/opacity problem still exits in the original code which is correct in that aspect.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array. If you want to access a specific item in that array you'll have to use its index.

Comment: Also, it can only be used from the `document` object, and not from DOM nodes.

Comment: So the answer is, "because you're doing it wrong"

Comment: Thanks for the replies - so many good answers to choose from, I feel guilty having to only mark one as correct when they are all good. I'll give it to Chase as his was the first and is alredy upvoted by somebody.

Comment: A follow up question - there is no setComputedStyle, what is the correct way to change the opacity at runtime?

Comment: At runtime, just use the style declaration: `title[0].style.opacity = .5;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`title.style.opacity`

should be:

`title[0].style.opacity`

since getElementsByTagName returns a nodeList.

EDIT:

This still doesn't get the value. You'll need to do the following:

`window.getComputedStyle(title[0]).opacity`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/f2ne6/12/

Answer (score 3):

For two reasons:

1. [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a list of elements, not a single element as `getElementById()`. Thus, you need to subscript the resulting `NodeList` to get the required DOM element;
2. Most importantly, when you access the styles through the `style` property of the element, you'll only get the ***inline*** styles, ***not*** the ones that you assign through a **CSS class**.

To get the *computed* styles, you could use **[`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)**, which will give you the final used values of *all* the CSS properties of the element:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(title).opacity);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/upB7y/)**.

Unfortunately, `getComputedStyle` is not [available](http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle) in IE < 9, but you can easily find a polyfill, such as [this](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/) one.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the style property of an HTML element (in the DOM) does not contain the computed style, it contains the immediately defined style of the element. Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="one" style="width: 50px;"></div>
```

If you call `document.getElementById("one").style.width`, you'll get `"50px"` back. However, if you remove the `style` attribute and instead use CSS to style the div to have a width of 50 pixels, it will return `""`. You can see this in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aAbJY/

You're probably looking for the computed style, which can be obtained in most browsers using `getComputedStyle()`. It doesn't work in IE until IE9, though there's probably a way to do it in IE<9. The computed style will return the opacity no matter where it's defined. See an updated example with `getComputedStyle()` here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aAbJY/1/

Comment: for the explanation on the inline style +1

Answer (score 0):

Chase is correct, but there's another problem in your code.  The `style` property only contains styles that were set with the `style` attribute of the element, so Chase's solution will only go halfway to fixing your problem.  What you want to do is use the `getComputedStyle()` function to get the runtime style of your element:

```
 function test(id) {
     var listElement = document.getElementById(id);
     var titles = listElement.getElementsByTagName("div");
     var style = getComputedStyle(titles[0]);
     alert( "Opacity: " + style.opacity );
 }
```

See my updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vQ4A/1/